# Can't seem to clean static files cache manually

Tags: magento2, frontend

i'm very new in magento2 and i'm following the official docs.

I'm playing around trying to change some css styles in the homepage but i seem to have issues with clearing the static files cache manually.

if i go to the admin panel and go to System > Tools > Cache Management and click Flush Static Files Cache it *does* work and i can see the changes i made on the website just fine.

But if i want to do it manually by deleting certain files with

> "rm -rf var/cache/*"

i get the error

> "zsh: no matches found: var/cache/*"

Can anyone please help me understand what's wrong? Why don't i have those directories?

Answer (score 0):

You can flush static files with the following command :

```
rm -rf pub/static/*
```

Note : Be sure to `cd` to the magento folder before running  this command.

More generally, here is a command to clear all caches, static files, generated classes, ... :

```
bin/magento c:f && rm -rf pub/static/* var/page_cache/* var/cache/* var/composer_home/* var/view_preprocessed/* generated/code/* generated/metadata/*
```